# Dll Export Function and opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, dll

I am experimenting with using `opencv` and `unity`. I have tried to make a function to open the camera and another one to close it:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "camera.h"
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

#define DllExport   __declspec( dllexport )

cameraControl mycam;
HANDLE threadCamera;
int threadCameraNumber = 0;

extern "C"
{
    DWORD WINAPI cameraStart(LPVOID lpParam)
    {       
             mycam.captureStart();
             return 0;
    }

    DllExport void cameraRun()
    {
            threadCamera = CreateThread(NULL, 0, cameraStart, &threadCameraNumber, 0, NULL);
    }

    DllExport void cameraStop()
    {
             mycam.captureEnd();    
    }
}
```

The thing is when I call the first function `cameraRun()` it opens the cam but when I call the second function `cameraStop()` it does not do anything.

Answer (score 0):

This might help:
http://opencv.jp/opencv-1.0.0_org/docs/ref/opencvref_highgui.htm

cvQueryFrame
Grabs and returns a frame from camera or file

IplImage* cvQueryFrame( CvCapture* capture );
capture
video capturing structure.
The function cvQueryFrame grabs a frame from camera or video file, decompresses and returns it. This function is just a combination of cvGrabFrame and cvRetrieveFrame in one call. The returned image should not be released or modified by user.

Comment: my problem not in opencv it's on dll